# Dart: How to use Youtube Data API to upload videos?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload videos on Youtube using [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis), I tried this:

```dart
    import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart';
    import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
    
    final _credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
    {
      "private_key_id": ...,
      "private_key": ...,
      "client_email": ...,
      "client_id": ...,
      "type": "service_account"
    }
    ''');
    
    const _scopes = [YouTubeApi.youtubeUploadScope];
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      final httpClient = await clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _scopes);
      try {
        final youtube = YouTubeApi(httpClient);
        
        youtube.videos.insert(request, part);  //What do to here??
    
      } finally {
        httpClient.close();
      }
    }
```

Now I don't know how to proceed next? I didn't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: Have you looked at https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/youtube.v3/youtube.v3-library.html

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use a ServiceAccountCredentials with the YouTube Data api.

You should be aware that the YouTube data api does not support service account authentication you will need to use OAuth2 and authorize a user.